# Is there the possibility to set a single component of a boost quaternion?

Tags: c++, boost, quaternions

I am trying to set a single component of a boost quaternion.
At first, in my foolishness I tried:

```
quat.R_component_1() = 5.0;
```

and of course this did not work.
I had a closer look at the [header file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/math/quaternion.hpp) of boost quaternions and it seems that there is no possibility to set a single component of a quaternion. You are able to set the whole quaternion by a constructor, but not a single component.

Does anybody know a possibility to set a single component of a boost quaternion, without setting the whole quaternion with a constructor?

Comment: Why would you set just one component? A quaternion is a math entity that doesn't exist in this state, it's always complete. What's your use case?

Comment: At irst, I have to say, that i do not really need to do this. I thought of an use case, when you have a set of points which you want to be rotated by a quaternion but before you want to manipulate the point data, maybe by setting one component to a special value. So you have your point data represented as quaternion cause of the quaternion rotation and you need to set a single component before.
I know that there are other possibilities to do this. My use case is just that  I read a quaternion rotation from a file and I wanted to set the single components successively .

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but what I gather from "before you want to manipulate the point data maybe by setting one component to a special value" is that you want to use a quaternion for something it's not designed for. Thus it can't work.

Comment: About setting the single components successively, you'll have to use variables to store the components separately and then build the quaternion once with these.

Comment: I know that I can do this by storing the values in variables. This is what I do.

But a quaternion is used for rotations, right? Just imagine if you are doing some quaternion roations with point data. First, you need to store the point data as quaternions to rotate them with quaternion multiplication. At this point you are going to manipulate the final point data by setting a component, e.g. to zero. I don't know if there is a real reason or a algorithm for this use case, but I am wondering about it. And after this you want to use these point data for another quaternion rotation.

Comment: For this it would be inefficient to overwrite the whole point data by new quaternions, cause you just want to set a single component. That is what I am thinking about.

Comment: @DanceIgel it's a bit of  stretch to assert that it's inefficient. Have you profiled that? Or looked at the generated code?

Comment: @sehe I did not profile this, but for me it seems to be logical that 1 assignement is more efficient than 4. But you are right, I didn't profile this (I even can't profile this, since there is no possibility to use a single component assignment.) and I may be wrong.

Comment: I'd not be surprised on modern CPUs assigning single values might be slower because it require reloading the MMS registers.